# Puma phased-restart fails when Gemfile is changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, puma

I'm using Puma as application server for my Rails 4 project on MRI 2.1.0. I'm using Capistrano 3 to handle deployments. Everything is working like a charm. But, I recently noticed an issue with my deployment process. If I change my Gemfile then, puma fails to complete phased-restart and eventually all workers get killed. I'm running Puma in cluster mode and `preload_app!` is set true.

Here is my Capistrano recipe to handle phased-restart.

```
desc "Restart the application (phased restart)"
task :phased_restart do
  on roles(:app) do |h|
    execute "cd #{fetch(:current_path)} && bundle exec pumactl -S #{fetch(:puma_state)}     phased-restart", :pty => true
  end
end
```

This is truncated output of Capistrano log.

```
DEBUG [4790766f] Command: cd /home/app/current && bundle exec pumactl -S /home/app/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state phased-restart
DEBUG [de00176a]    Command phased-restart sent success
 INFO [de00176a] Finished in 0.909 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

This is my `config/puma.rb` file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env puma
require 'active_support'

environment 'production'
daemonize
pidfile '/home/app/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid'
state_path '/home/app/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state'
stdout_redirect 'log/puma_stdout.log', 'log/puma_stderr.log'
threads 100, 100

bind 'tcp://0.0.0.0:9292'
bind 'unix:////home/app/shared/tmp/pids/puma.sock'

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/database.yml")[Rails.env])
  end
end
workers 4
preload_app!
```

Does anybody see anything wrong in my puma config file?

So, currently I do `bundle exec cap production deploy:start` to start Puma when this happens. But, I want zero-downtime-deployment in every cases.

Can Puma keep using old worker processes in case new spawned processes couldn't be started?

Answer (score 6):

Do you know that preload_app! conflicts with phased restarts?

Proof: https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/0ea7af5e2cc8fa192ec82934a4a47880bdb592f8/lib/puma/configuration.rb#L333-L335

I think first you need to decide which to use.

Answer (score 4):

For doing a phased restart you need to enable the prune_bundler option and disable preload_app!
See https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/DEPLOYMENT.md#restarting

To do zero-downtime deploys with Capistrano, you can use the capistrano3-puma gem with the following options:

```
set :puma_preload_app, false
set :puma_prune_bundler, true
```